# I crashed Docker with container overload, how do I remove them?

Tags: docker

**My Story**

Once upon a time I was calling [Docker](http://docker.com) from a PHP laravel queue to process thousands of media files.  My code would create a new container for each task I wanted to complete (e.g. "process", "search", "slice" etc).  Then I went to bed and disaster struck.  I woke up to a 1TB log file, and a few hundred thousand containers in various states.

Docker doesn't work anymore.  As in, when I type `docker version` (or `docker anything` for that matter) it just sits there and stares.  I can't remove the containers through the standard `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` because Docker has become very, very depressed.

Here is relevant information around how I'm currently calling the daemon:

```
$> sudo docker daemon
INFO[0000] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock
INFO[0000] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver "aufs"

(Meanwhile in another terminal)
$> docker version
(insert infinite darkness here)
```

**My Questions**

1. How can I remove docker containers if the docker daemon isn't responding?
2. I'm using Docker as a glorified executable being called from code using their API.  What extra steps do I need my code take to clean after itself in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did some digging.

> How can I remove docker containers if the docker daemon isn't responding?

In Ubuntu, containers are stored in the `/var/lib/docker/containers` directory.  Delete the contents of that directory and things are just that much better.

Also, for anybody curious, there were around 250k containers that had to be removed.  Given the number of files I had to go with `ls /var/lib/docker/containers | xargs -n200 rm -rf`

> I'm using Docker as a glorified executable being called from code using their API. What extra steps do I need my code take to clean after itself in future?

If the container isn't going to be used again, you should officially "remove" it after you're done.  On command line this would be done using `docker rm $(containername)` and in code it will completely depend on how docker is being accessed.

Comment: You also might want to consider `docker rm -v`, because otherwise volumes will remain. Or better yet: [Use `docker run --rm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up-rm).